# Spring Rest Controller url mapping inheritance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I have multiple REST controllers and would like all the url's to have "/rest" as the common url pattern.

E.g. 
    (1) UserController: http://localhost:9000/rest/user
    (2) TicketController: http://localhost:9000/rest/ticket

Is there a way i can achieve this?

I tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest")
public abstract class BaseController { }

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/ticket")
public class TicketController extends BaseController{ 

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Ticket createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket){
    return ticketService.createTicket(ticket);      
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the RequestMapping on TicketController to "ticket" instead of "/ticket" ?

Comment: It throws an error: Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: RequestMapping on class-level in TicketController is overwriting the Mapping defined in BaseController. Only on method-level is supported and in your case /rest is added if you have only annotated methods with RequestMapping.